# Tag for burnation - [new]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, blacklist

I've just noticed we have a [new](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/new) tag.

I can't see any benefit for such a tag - so it needs removing. There's at least one question where this is the only tag so it has to be a manual process.

There are currently <strike>32</strike> 33 questions so tagged.

Once the tag has been removed perhaps it can be blacklisted?

Comment: Burninate! With extreme prejudice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree. I don't see the point in having a [new](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/new) tag.
Going through all the questions, none of the questions using the new tag can actually justify its use.
It might be valid to have a tag like say, "new-devices", if it is justified in the question. But simply using "new" is worthless

Comment: In what cases would `new-devices` be useful to classify or group questions?

Comment: What I wished to imply was `new` alone is absolutely worthless. If you make in a little more specific, it "might" just be acceptable. `new-devices` was just something I wrote off the top of my head as an example.